# Find the Basis and Dimension of a Solution Space for homogeneous systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
x+2y-2z+2s-t=0\\
x+2y-z+3s-2t=0\\
2x+4y-7z+s+t=0
\end{array}\right.$$

Which forms the following matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
1 & 2 & -1 & 3 & -2 & 0\\
2 & 4 & -7 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

Which I then row reduced to the following form:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & 2 & 0 & 4 & -3 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]$$

I am unsure from this point how to find the basis for the solution set.  Any help of direction would be appreciated.  I know that the dimension would be $n-r$ where $n$ is the number of unknowns and $r$ is the rank of the matrix but I do not know how to find the basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First solve the system, assigning parameters to the variables which correspond to non-leading (non-pivot) columns:
$$\eqalign{
  &t=\alpha\cr
  &s=\beta\cr
  z+s-t=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad &z=\alpha-\beta\cr
  &y=\gamma\cr
  x+2y+4s-3t=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad &x=3\alpha-4\beta-2\gamma\ .\cr}$$
So the solution set is
$$\left\{\pmatrix{3\alpha-4\beta-2\gamma\cr \gamma\cr \alpha-\beta\cr \beta\cr \alpha\cr}\ \Bigg|\ \alpha,\beta,\gamma\in{\Bbb R}\right\}$$
which can be written
$$\left\{\alpha\pmatrix{3\cr0\cr1\cr0\cr1\cr}+\beta\pmatrix{-4\cr0\cr-1\cr1\cr0\cr}+\gamma\pmatrix{-2\cr1\cr0\cr0\cr0\cr}\ \Bigg|\ \alpha,\beta,\gamma\in{\Bbb R}\right\}\ .$$
The three vectors shown span the solution set; it is also not too hard to prove that they are linearly independent; therefore they form a basis for the solution set.

Comment: So the basis of the solution set is simply the linearly independent vectors in the solution set?  Am I understanding this correctly or is that an oversimplification of the concept?

Comment: That's pretty right, although perhaps you are just a little bit oversimplifying when you say "**the** linearly independent vectors in the solution set".  The point is that there will not be just one choice of independent vectors: for example, if you let $x,z,s$ be parameters instead of $y,s,t$ then you would get a different basis which is also correct.