# How to find a basis for the solution space of a linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

How to find a basis for the solution space of this linear system?
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Solutions are $[-2t, -3t, t ]$ because $x_3$ is a free variable. So let $x_3 = t$.

But how do I find the basis for this?

This is a system $Ax=0$

Comment: Choose some "good" value for $\;t\;$ (Almost all of them will work)

Comment: See also some other similar posts. For example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940856/find-the-basis-and-dimension-of-a-solution-space-for-homogeneous-systems or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603228/find-basis-of-solutions-of-this-linear-system (And maybe some other posts listed among related questions in the sidebar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_4$ is also free variable. So the solution should be $[-2t,-3t,t,s]$ where $t,s\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore the solution can be written as 
$$[-2t,-3t,t,s]=t[-2,-3,1,0]+s[0,0,0,1].$$
That is to say, the solution is linear combination of $[-2,-3,1,0]$ and $[0,0,0,1]$, and they are linearly independent. So $\big\{[-2,-3,1,0],[0,0,0,1]\big\}$ is a basis.

Comment: No, sorry. It's  a homogeneous system. 3 equations and 3 unknowns.

Comment: @Alyssa, that's a piece of info that you should include in the question, so that people will know that matrix is is the extended one of the system.

Comment: But there are four columns in your matrix.

Comment: It's 1x1 +0x2 + 2x3 =0 for the first row.

Comment: So you stated your problem in the wrong way. Your $A$ is a $3\times 4$ matrix, so the system is $Ax=0$ where $x$ is a column vector of four variables, and $0$ on the right hand side is the zero column vector.